# How to get SPProductNumber via Client Object Model?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-apps, sharepoint-clientobject

I am looking for way to get `SPProductNumber`via client object model. I have sharepoint app, and I need to connect client application and that app. To do this I need to get SPProductNumber. If there is not way, anyone know how to check it with Sharepoint GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using the following code:

CSOM (e.g. C#)

```
ClientContext.ServerVersion
```

JavaScript:

```
SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_serverVersion()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I needed the exact same functionality today and didn't found a list what property returns what in which situation.

The ClientContext object has a few properties regarding to versions which are explained by Microsoft in this way:

- ClientContext.ServerVersion: Gets the version of the current
  SharePoint Server.
- ClientRuntimeContext.ServerLibraryVersion: Gets the build version of
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll on the server.
- ClientRuntimeContext.ServerSchemaVersion: Gets the schema version of
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime.dll on the server.
- ClientRuntimeContext.RequestSchemaVersion: Gets of sets the schema version of the request. If this value is not set, the default
  value is equal to the value of the CurrentVersion property. For
  example, for a client running Microsoft Office 2013 to communicate
  with a server running Microsoft Office 2010, the value
  RequestSchemaVersion must be set to “14.0.0.0”. Otherwise, the server
  will reject the request.

I did some tests in C# with the CSOM libraries (v16.0.3104.1200 & v15.0.4711.1000) and these are the results when connecting to different SharePoint environments. The subversions can be different depending on which updates are installed on the SharePoint environments.

```
SharePoint 2010:
ClientContext.ServerVersion: 14.0.4762.1000
ClientContext.ServerLibraryVersion: 14.0.4762.1000
ClientContext.ServerSchemaVersion: 14.0.0.0
ClientContext.RequestSchemaVersion: 14.0.0.0

SharePoint 2013:
ClientContext.ServerVersion: 15.0.4667.1000
ClientContext.ServerLibraryVersion: 15.0.4667.1000
ClientContext.ServerSchemaVersion: 15.0.0.0
ClientContext.RequestSchemaVersion: 15.0.0.0

Office 365:
ClientContext.ServerVersion: 16.0.5701.1202
ClientContext.ServerLibraryVersion: 16.0.5701.1202
ClientContext.ServerSchemaVersion: 15.0.0.0
ClientContext.RequestSchemaVersion: 15.0.0.0
```

When testing with the CSOM libraries of SP2010 (v14.0.4762.1000) you cannot connect to an Office 365 environment (because it uses the SharePointOnlineCredentials which are not present in these libraries). Also the property RequestSchemaVersion is not known in these libraries. The results when connecting to SP2010 & SP2013:

```
SharePoint 2010:
ClientContext.ServerVersion: 14.0.4762.1000
ClientContext.ServerLibraryVersion: 14.0.4762.1000
ClientContext.ServerSchemaVersion: 14.0.0.0

SharePoint 2013
ClientContext.ServerVersion: 15.0.4667.1000
ClientContext.ServerLibraryVersion: 15.0.4667.1000
ClientContext.ServerSchemaVersion: 14.0.0.0 // (this one is different from above)
```